# Java - cant understand error message

Tags: java

I'm new at Java and I have started out with a tutorial... The tutorial wants you to start this way:

```
package proj;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Proj extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

   }

}
```

But I get an error message on the class Proj, that is saying: "Proj is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener".

I don't quite understand what this error message means, and in the tutorial this isn't mentioned.

Comment: **does not override abstract method actionPerformed** i think, for now, you should focus on this part only

Comment: If this is only the first step, it's probably not necessary for it to compile yet. At some point, you'll need to write an `actionPerformed` method.

Comment: That message means, that you need the **actionPerformed** method in your class; this is because the class implements ActionListener. The missing method is declared in the ActionListener interface.

Comment: I'd suggest it's not a great tutorial if it doesn't at least touch on the exception or explain it properly.

Comment: Always remember when you do `implements` you MUST override all of the methods in the interface (exception in Java 8 though), and this is the very basic that should be learnt while learning Java :)

Answer (score 3):

Your class Proj implements an interface. An interface can "tell" which methods a class, implementing this interface, has to implement. The `ActionListener` interface guarantees that a class implementing this interface has also to implement said method `actionPerformed(...)`. So in order to fix this: Implement said method.

No offense, but: You might want to take a look into some Java starter tutorials or books.

Comment: "You might want to take a look into some Java starter tutorials or books." He specifically said that he got this error while following a tutorial.

Comment: Then I should correct this to: a better tutorial (at least if the tutorial assumes that the code compiles)

Answer (score 3):

`ActionListener` is an [Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html) containing the method `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)`. When you implement an interface, you agree to create an implementation of all methods declared in said interface.

You have not implemented the `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` method that's in the interface you told the Java compiler you would implement, hence the error. You also have to make sure to use the same modifiers for the method as in the interface, in this case `public void`.

I suspect the tutorial you are following will get to this, you probably just tried to compile the program prematurely. If not, I'd send an email to the owner of the tutorial!

Answer (score 1):

If a class implements a interface, it should implement all the method in that interface, unless it's an abstract class

`ActionListener` is an interface in Java, and your class Proj is not an abstract class, so You must implement `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` method appropriately defined in that interface.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the actionPerformed method.

Answer (score 0):

ActionListener is a interface. Interfaces declares methods, but don't include its body. When you implement a interface you should provide a body for inherited method or declare it as abstract (saying: hey! my subclass should implement it).

Comment: Not quite. The _class_ needs to be declared abstract.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I thought that it inherits the abstractness of the method.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Only abstract class is required. I have just check it out. My mistake, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the missing method for ActionListner interface.